# CSS selected/active property

Tags: css

I have twelve `<a href>` links that lead to different categories. As a means of orientation for the user I would like to emphasise the very category (`<a href>`-button) that the user is in right now.

How can I achieve this in CSS? I read about `selected` and `active`, but I haven't been able to make it work yet.

This is one of the links/buttons:

```
<a href="index.php?category=handy&location=&sort="><span class="category_item"></span><span class="category_description">Handy & Co.</span></a>
```

The corresponding CSS:

```
.category_item {
display:inline-block;
background:url(../img/category_item/ph.png) no-repeat;
width: 45px;
height: 45px;   
margin-right: 11px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.category_item:hover {
background:url(../img/category_item/hover.png);
}

.category_description {
position: absolute;
font-size: 11px;
color: #000;
margin-top: 43px;
margin-left: -62px;
z-index: 1;
opacity: 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Need to do this with something other than CSS.  Something has to apply the class to the link that styles it as the current page's link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run some jquery code when you load the page that checks the link urls with the current page's url and setting a class on the links that match.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/og4o1tdh/2/

something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="categories">
    <a href="www.google.com"><span class="category_description">Google</span></a>
    <!-- jsfiddle code is apparently run on fiddle.jshell.net -->
    <a href="fiddle.jshell.net"><span class="category_description">JSFiddle</span></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#categories a').each(function (){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(link) > -1) {
        $(this).find('span').addClass('currentCategory');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.currentCategory {
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: just one question: how can I target the `span` (inside the `a`) rather than the whole `a`?

Comment: you can do `$(this).find('span').addClass('currentCategory');`. I just updated my answer to have this change. If you want to specifically add it to the `category_description` span then do: `$(this).find('.category_description').addClass('currentCategory');`

Comment: nice! glad to help =)

Answer (score 0):

To give a special class to an anchor when a user clicks you can use simple javascript and jQuery.

Give all the anchor's you want to be in the scope of this a class for instance:

**HTML:**

`<a class="nav-link" href="http://www.google.com"> Google </a>
<a class="nav-link" href="http://www.yahoo.com"> Yahoo </a>`

**Javascript:**

`$(".nav-link").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
});`

To make sure you only have one anchor with "active" class I would do the following:

`$(".nav-link").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav-link").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active")
});`

Comment: You might not have understood my question. An anchor has to be styled differently ONLY if the user is currently on the page the anchor leads to. So that the user knows in which category he's currently in. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way of knowing which link is the current one. The easiest way may be to use javascript to check the current URL by `document.URL` and add a CSS class to the link with an equal `href` attribute. Then, you may style this class in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't know what page you are on.

To do this you will have to change your HTML markup, for example: to add:

`<a class="current-page" href="index.php?category=handy&location=&sort=" ...`

on the relevant link which you can use to 'hook' an new CSS style onto:

`.current-page { color: red;  }`

The alternative is to use Javascript to 'read' the URL and apply a style.

Comment: I'm looking for something like `li.selected a`, this worked for another case on my website... Just adding another class doesn't do it, because the `color` is going to be `red` in every situation, if the button is clicked or not

Answer (score 0):

You could...

1. Simply add a unique classname to the `body` tag or (some element that wraps around the anchor tags). And then style your links accordingly. This option is quite easy if you have access to change the HTML in your pages:

**HTML**

```
<body class="category_handy">
...
<a href="..." class="category_handy">
<span class="category_item"></span>
<span class="category_description">Handy & Co.</span>
</a> 
....
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body.category_handy a.category_handy {
  color:red;
}
body.category_dandy a.category_dandy {
  color:yellow;
}
body.category_something a.category_something {
  color: blue;
}
```

2. If you don't have access to directly edit each page, you may have to dynamically check the URL, and then add a classname (like "current") to the anchor tag who's href attribute matches.

Either way, the solution will not involve "css only".